# Local website - insert file into e-mail

Tags: javascript, html, email

I have a local-only website that many people in an office access. Among many other things, it's purpose is to have links to many Word documents, Excel workbooks, PDFs, etc. that are saved to a networked drive.

Some people would like to be able to quickly insert those files into an e-mail, perhaps with a single click.

The best solution I have come up with is using Internet Explorer and link to the folder in which the file is located. And from there, you could drag or copy and paste the file into a new e-mail. I'm hoping there's a much better alternative though.

Since it is an internal, local-only website, I *think* my options are limited to HTML and JavaScript. Can this be done?

Comment: By "local only" do you mean this is an HTML file that people open from the file system?  Or that this is a website people access on a LAN?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. There's a shared networked drive, that has a folder full of HTML files and such, like you would have on a web server.

Comment: What I mean is, how do users access this website?  Is it actually a web server, or just files on a shared drive?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. No, it is not a web server.

Comment: Then yes, that does limit your options significantly.  At that point this is just an HTML file which can link to things.  If you can have an actual web application on a LAN-based web server then you'd have more functionality available to you.  It can show file lists from shared locations, expose operations to "send a file" and use server-side code to perform those operations, etc.

Comment: Right. I've been trying to get someone to set that up for me for years. It probably isn't possible at this point. Is that the only way to make this work?

Comment: Well, it's probably the *best* way, but might not be the only way.  How about an executable application instead of an HTML file?  That would be "opened" the same way as the current HTML file, but would give you the option of using more code than just some simple JavaScript on a page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130022/discussion-between-robby-and-david).